# MVC and classic ASPX app in same domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am converting an classic aspx app to MVC.

Within classic aspx app there is another app as follows:

foo.com/ - main app.

foo.com/bar/ - contains another app.

I m rewriting foo.com with MVC and curious how I can store foo.com/bar/ within MVC app. should i create another folder and store the aspx app for foo.com/bar in this folder?

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: just noticed but: there is a huge difference between classic ASP en ASP.NET. Which one exactly are you refering to?

Comment: .aspx = .NET
.asp = classic asp
It just sounds confusing, but I'm guessing .NET from the tags you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

Use area's :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

But I would only do that if the apps work with each other, thus are related.

If the apps are completely stand-alone, I would advise you to make a subfolder.
This makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: I am not developing the other app, so i m not using areas. and i dont wanna break the other app.

Comment: Then I would go for a subfolder, you wouldn't even have to actually include the app to make it work.